# GSON: Cannot correctly parse JSON object

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to parse a JSON object like the following with GSON:

```
{
 "key1":"someValue",
 "key2":{   
            "anotherKey1":"212586425",
            "anotherKey2":"Martin"
         }
}
```

This is the code:

```
Data data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Data.class);
```

Here is the `Data` class:

```
public class Data {

        public String key1;
        public Map key2; //This will break everything.
}
```

What I expect (I am new to GSON) is that it produces the value of `key2` as a `Map` object.

However, I get an error `Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING` which makes me think that I am passing a `String`, where I should be passing a JSON object.

Isn't GSON parsing the whole JSON string I pass in the beginning? So eventually, I would like the new data source to be a `Map` Object. Is that feasible ?

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure you are using the correct JSON?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Strange. Structure is completely the same in my JSON object. Cannot get it to work though...

Comment: Can you print out the JSON you are trying to parse?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ok I think the problem is kind of solved. Sometimes my JSON object contains Strings for key2 as opposed to key-value pairs, which causes it to crash.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can I define custom setters in the Data class ? I tried to, but they do not seem to be called...

Comment: I believe `Gson`, by default, injects the `Field`s directly, without using the accessors. You might be able to change this behavior, but I don't know how. Consider looking into other JSON parsers like Jackson, which I think comes with that functionality out of the box.

Comment: Oh no...! Alright thanks anyway :-)

Comment: It's true that Gson injects fields directly, but you do not to switch to other parser to solve this. I can show you how, if you have the patient to wait 3 hours (not for coding solution, but just I have to go out :) )

Comment: @trapo never mind... I don't need it anymore :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't leave question without answers :) I hope this is the same way you used to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Let Gson do the work. I defined `Data` as

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19228349;

public class Data {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data [key1=" + key1 + ", key2=" + key2 + "]";
    }
    public String key1;
    public Object key2;

}
```

and then I can parse both cases for `key2`:

```
package stackoverflow.questions.q19228349;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Q19228349 {


    public static void main(String[] args){
    String json =
            "{\"key1\":\"someValue\","+
            "\"key2\":{   "+
            "           \"anotherKey1\":\"212586425\","+
            "           \"anotherKey2\":\"Martin\""+
            "        }"+
            " }";

    String json2 =
            "{\"key1\":\"someValue\","+
            "\"key2\":\"aString\""+
            " }";

        Gson g = new Gson();
        Data d = g.fromJson(json, Data.class); 
        System.out.println("First: " +d);

        Data d2 = g.fromJson(json2, Data.class); 
        System.out.println("Second: "+d2);
    }


}
```

This is the result:

> First: Data [key1=someValue, key2={anotherKey1=212586425,
>   anotherKey2=Martin}] Second: Data [key1=someValue, key2=aString]